# Postgres set varchar field to regular expression of itself

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to normalise a data field by removing a fairly common postfix. I've got as far as using the **substring()** function in postgres, but can't quite get it to work. For example, if I want to strip the postfix 'xyz' from any values that have it;

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field=substring(my_field from '#"%#"xyz' for '#');
```

But this is having some weird effects that I cant pin down. Any thoughts? Many thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update my_table
   set my_field = regexp_replace(my_field, 'xyz$', '')
where my_field ~ 'xyz$';
```

This will also change the value `'xyz'` into an empty string. I don't know if you want that (or if the suffix can exists "on it's own".

The where clause is not strictly necessary but will make the update more efficient because only those rows are updated that actually meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_field = left(my_field, -3)
WHERE  my_field LIKE '%xyz';
```

For several reasons:

- If you don't want to change every single row, **always** add a `WHERE` clause to your `UPDATE`. Even if only some rows are actually changed by the expression. An `UPDATE` from the same value to the same value is still an `UPDATE` and will produce dead rows and table bloat and trigger triggers ...
- Use `left()` in combination with `LIKE`.

  - `left()` with a negative second parameter effectively trims the number of character from the end of the string. `left()` was introduced with PostgreSQL 9.1. I quote the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

  > When n is negative, return all but last |n| characters.

  - Always pick  `LIKE` over a regular expression (`~`) if you can. `LIKE` is not as versatile, but much faster. (`SIMILAR TO` is rewritten as regular expression internally). Details in this [related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684).

---

If you want to make sure that a minimum of characters remains:

```
WHERE  my_field LIKE '_%xyz'; -- prepend as many _ as you want chars left
```

---

`substring()` would work like this (one possibility):

```
substring(my_field, '^(.*)xyz$');
```